# Swift filter for multiple dictionary keys

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I'm making a search bar for my app. I'm using the `filter` method to get the results. I want to search through multiple keys.

Array of dictionaries:

```
var people = [
               ["First": "John", "Last": "Doe"],
               ["First": "Steve", "Last": "Jobs"],
               ["First": "Elon", "Last": "Musk"]
             ]
```

I am only able to search for either "First" or "Last", but not both, with this code:

```
searchResults = people.filter{
            var string = $0["Last"] 
            // or "First"

            string = string?.lowercaseString

            return string!.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) != nil
        }
```

Comment: Is this the real code you're using? You're missing a `"` after `Steve` on the second line of your array of dictionaries.

Comment: The dictionary I am using is very large so I made a small one as an example, but the code for the search is what I am using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach would be to simply compare both fields to the search string:

```
var people = [
    ["First": "JohnMusk", "Last": "Doe"],
    ["First": "Steve", "Last": "Jobs"],
    ["First": "Elon", "Last": "Musk"]
]

var searchText = "Musk"

var searchResults = people.filter{
        var firstName = $0["First"]!.lowercaseString
        var lastName = $0["Last"]!.lowercaseString

       return firstName.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) != nil
              || lastName.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) != nil

}
```

This gives me this result:

```
2015-11-18 18:19:47.691 MyPlayground[36558:7031733] (
        {
        First = JohnMusk;
        Last = Doe;
    },
        {
        First = Elon;
        Last = Musk;
    }
)
```

Which I believe is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternate approach using `NSPredicate`. `NSPredicate` has a very powerful [syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) which can do some pretty nice things for you.

```
let firstNameQuery = "jo"
let lastNameQuery = "mus"
// [cd] means case/diacritic insensitive. %K is used to pass in key names since FIRST and LAST are reserved keywords in NSPredicate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR %K CONTAINS[cd] %@", "First", firstNameQuery, "Last", lastNameQuery)
let sorted = people.filter({
    return predicate.evaluateWithObject($0)
})
// sorted would contain John Doe and Elon Musk entries
```

In my example I passed in different search queries for the first and last name, but you could obviously pass in the same query for both. Just demonstrates the power of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should works:

```
var people = [
        ["First": "John", "Last": "Doe"],
        ["First": "Steve", "Last": "Jobs"],
        ["First": "Elon", "Last": "Musk"]
        ]


  let searchResults = people.filter{

    var found = false
    let searText = "Elon"
    for str in $0.values {
        found = str.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searText.lowercaseString) != nil
        if found {
            break
        }
    }
   return found
}
```