# How to search data from multiple keys of dictionary?

Tags: ios, search, nspredicate

In my application having search functionality and I want to search value from multiple keys. This is my dictionary:

```
 notifications =     (
                {
            "beautician_name" = "ABC";
            "booking_date" = "2016-12-12";
            "date_time" = "2016-12-12 11:27:42";
            discount = 25%;
            "service_name" = Tanning;
            "sub_service_name" = "Spray Tan";
            title = Cancellation;
        },
        {
            "beautician_name" = "PQR";
            "booking_date" = "2016-12-11";
            "date_time" = "2016-12-12 11:27:42";
            discount = 25%;
            "service_name" = hair;
            "sub_service_name" = "Spray Tan";
            title = Cancellation;
        },
        {   
            "beautician_name" = "XYZ";
            "booking_date" = "2016-12-15";
            "date_time" = "2016-12-12 11:27:42";
            discount = 25%;
            "service_name" = film;
            "sub_service_name" = "Spray Tan";
            title = Cancellation;
        }
)
```

I want to search data from these keys: "beautician_name", "booking_date", "discount", "sub_service_name". I want to predicate not any for loop or etc.

Comment: Please specify on which key(s) you want to perform search...elaborate more

Comment: @sanman please check my updated ans

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793427/swift-filter-for-multiple-dictionary-keys (santa claus's answer) , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980618/using-nspredicate-to-filter-based-on-multiple-keys-not-values-for-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested it, please try something like this below.

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"beautician_name contains[c] %@ OR booking_date contains[c] %@ OR discount contains[c] %@ OR sub_service_name contains[c] %@" ,searchText,searchText,searchText,searchText];
        NSArray *SearchResult = [notifications filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```